# Angular 2 get request response

Tags: angular

I am trying to dealing with success and failure return from response, when I get response in literat it give me error in contoller

Here's my service code

```
  authentication(userName : string, password:string){
  return this.http.get(this.url).map(data=>{
    data.json()
  });
```

here's my controller code

```
this.authenticationservice.authentication(this.UserName, this.Password)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status != null) {
        switch (response.status) {
          case 'Success':
            this.response = response.message;
            console.log(this.response);
            break;
          case 'Failure':
            this.response = response.message;
            this.loginStat = true;
            break;
        }
      }
    })
```

It give me error om response.status and response.message

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something from the `map` response:

```
authentication(userName : string, password:string){
  return this.http.get(this.url).map(data=>{
    return data.json(); //<-- return this
  });
}
```